# Why use AUFS as the default Docker storage backend instead of devicemapper?

Tags: docker

Project Atomic's description of Docker [storage backends](http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/filesystems/) describes technical differences between AUFS and other storage backend choices, such as devicemapper.  [AUFS](http://aufs.sourceforge.net) is not in the upstream Linux kernel.  Why is AUFS chosen as the default storage backend (for example in Ubuntu's Docker)? Are there some technical properties of AUFS that makes it a better choice than a storage backend such as devicemapper that seems to be supported by an unpatched Linux kernel?

Comment: This information is obsolete. The default storage backend is now `overlay2`, which is now available on all distributions and more reliable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AUFS is only the default storage back end on systems/distributions that have it available. Otherwise, devicemapper is the default. Ubuntu 14.04, for example, defaults to devicemapper:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
$ docker info | grep Storage
Storage Driver: devicemapper
```

This changed in [Docker 0.7.0](http://blog.docker.com/2013/11/docker-0-7-docker-now-runs-on-any-linux-distribution/). Prior to 0.7.0, Docker relied upon AUFS as its only storage driver, which is why it was the default in earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: Interesting that Ubuntu 14.04 also defaults to devicemapper.  However, the link says: "If your system supports AUFS, it will continue to use the AUFS driver". What about AUFS makes Docker prefer it over devicemapper, if available?

Comment: Just that if a system has aufs support with docker prior to 0.7, they would still want their images to work. If the storage driver changed the images would be incompatible, thus breaking those systems. There is no technical benefit to us info aufs over device mapper.

Comment: We have performance issues on AWS with devicemapper (m3.medium instance, EBS disk mounted to /var/lib/docker dir). With btrfs/etx4 filesystem and devicemapper we have build times around 20 minutes. With btrfs filesystem and btrfs devicemapper we lower build times to 12 minutes. With ext4 filesystem and aufs devicemapper it takes around 6 minutes. So, there are differencies with performance levels on AWS infrastructure at least.

Comment: Certainly there are performance differences. devicemapper is much slower since it operates as a block device. But this question is about why devicemapper is the default, and the reason is not related to performance, but rather due to the lack of AUFS support in the kernel for most distributions.

Comment: It's only much slower if your LVM volume is not thinly provisioned (which it should be) or you aren't using LVM at all for some reason. Thin provisioning provides the copy on write semantics that Docker relies on for performance here.

Answer (score 7):

I'm far from an expert on filesystems, but the folks at Discourse, who are, [strongly recommend using AUFS, and not DeviceMapper](https://meta.discourse.org/t/cant-install-discourse-with-only-10-gb-disk-run-out-of-space/29149/34?u=dandv). Using DeviceMapper can result in "a world of pain".

[image: Why using DeviceMapper for Discourse sucks]

Comment: I'm struggling with an docker exit code 159 recently, which means some sort of file size limitation exceed. Finally I find out that it's caused by device mapper, so have to reinstalled docker and changed to use overlay driver.

Answer (score 0):

The [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-storage-driver) says:

> The aufs driver is the oldest, but is based on a Linux kernel patch-set that is unlikely to be merged into the main kernel. These are also known to cause some serious kernel crashes.

I had those kernel crashes with Docker 17.06.2~ce-0~ubuntu on Ubuntu 16.04 with default kernel.

I am using `overlay2` on ext4 file system; Docker now works fine.